# Mac doesn't respond after sleep mode: how to Prevent this?

Tags: sleep-wake, performance

My mac often doesn't respond after sleep mode. What can be the reason?

There are a lot of articles about what to do in this situation. But I can find nothing about how to Prevent it.

Mac is macbook Air. OS is OSx 10.7.4

Comment: Do the screen light up so you can see the desktop or is it just keyboard that light up and screen keeps black?

Comment: Different things.
One time it showed all windows and shows colored circle instead of mouse. Few times it was black screen with such a circle. Few times - just black screen.

Comment: Does the computer ever crash and ask you to reboot it? Reason I ask is that I had kind of the same problem with my MacBook Pro in Lion. In addition I had the problem that it crashed and wanted me to reboot after random time of waking up after sleep.

Comment: he never asked.:) I just had to do this having no other option

Comment: How did you fix the problem?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution that worked for me. What is interesting is that after I upgraded to Mountain Lion there is no longer any problem with waking the computer from sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I fixed it.
The problem was, that I divided my disk onto three logical disks. And system was confused, which one to be used for booting.
When I chose Startup Disk in System preferences (even though there was only one option) the laptop wakes up normally. (I had no problems during three days)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my mini.  The first thing you might try is resetting your [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and then your [PMU](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1431).  These control sleep on your mac.  If they fix it, and it goes bad again, you may need to take it in for warranty repair (if under warranty.)

Comment: I tried reset PRAM many times - no changes. There is no PMU on laptops, is it?

Comment: I think PMU is related to older laptops.  If none of those things fixed it, you could try waiting for the next version of the OS (lest it’s an OS issue) or try a clean install (you have a Time Machine backup, right?)  But it’s probably a trip to the Genius Bar for you.  Good Luck!